# how to parse a huge JSON file without loading it in memory

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a large JSON file (2.5MB) containing about 80000 lines.

It looks like this:

```
{
  "a": 123,
  "b": 0.26,
  "c": [HUGE irrelevant object],
  "d": 32
}
```

I only want the integer values stored for keys `a`, `b` and `d` and ignore the rest of the JSON (i.e. ignore whatever is there in the `c` value).

I cannot modify the original JSON as it is created by a 3rd party service, which I download from its server.

How do I do this without loading the entire file in memory?

I tried using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library and created the bean like this:

```
public class MyJsonBean {
  @SerializedName("a")
  @Expose
  public Integer a;

  @SerializedName("b")
  @Expose
  public Double b;

  @SerializedName("d")
  @Expose
  public Integer d;
}
```

but even then in order to deserialize it using Gson, I need to download + read the whole file in memory first and the pass it as a string to Gson?

```
File myFile = new File(<FILENAME>);
myFile.createNewFile();

URL url = new URL(<URL>);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile));
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

int numRead;
while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
}

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
fis.read(data);
String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");

Gson gson = new Gson();
MyJsonBean response = gson.fromJson(str, MyJsonBean.class);

System.out.println("a: " + response.a + "" + response.b + "" + response.d);
```

Is there any way to avoid loading the whole file and just get the relevant values that I need?

Comment: I feel like you're going to have to download the entire file and convert it to a String, but if you don't have an Object associated you at least won't any unnecessary Objects. Perhaps if the data is static-ish, you could make a layer in between, a small server that fetches the data, modifies it, and then you could fetch from there instead.

Comment: 2.5MB is not large.

Comment: with jackson: leave the field out and annotate with  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely check different approaches and libraries. If you are really take care about performance check: `Gson`, [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) and [`JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) libraries to do that and choose the fastest one. Definitely you have to load the whole `JSON` file on local disk, probably `TMP` folder and parse it after that.

Simple `JsonPath` solution could look like below:

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonPathApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.parse(jsonFile);
        System.out.println("" + documentContext.read("$.a"));
        System.out.println("" + documentContext.read("$.b"));
        System.out.println("" + documentContext.read("$.d"));
    }
}
```

Notice, that I do not create any `POJO`, just read given values using `JSONPath` feature similarly to `XPath`. The same you can do with `Jackson`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;

public class JsonPathApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        System.out.println(root.get("a"));
        System.out.println(root.get("b"));
        System.out.println(root.get("d"));
    }
}
```

We do not need `JSONPath` because values we need are directly in `root` node. As you can see, `API` looks almost the same. We can also create `POJO` structure:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class JsonPathApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Pojo pojo = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Pojo.class);
        System.out.println(pojo);
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Pojo {
    private Integer a;
    private BigDecimal b;
    private Integer d;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Even so, both libraries allow to read `JSON` payload directly from `URL` I suggest to download it in another step using best approach you can find. For more info, read this article: [Download a File From an URL in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file).

Answer (score 3):

There are some excellent libraries for parsing large JSON files with minimal resources. One is the popular [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson). It gets at the same effect of parsing the file as both stream and object. It handles each record as it passes, then discards the stream, keeping memory usage low.

If you’re interested in using the GSON approach, there’s a great tutorial for that here. [Detailed Tutorial](https://www.acuriousanimal.com/blog/2015/10/23/reading-json-file-in-stream-mode-with-gson)

Comment: The tutorial link is a 404

Answer (score 1):

> I only want the integer values stored for keys a, b and d and ignore the rest of the JSON (i.e. ignore whatever is there in the c value). ... How do I do this without loading the entire file in memory?

One way would be to use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)'s so-called streaming parser, invoked with the --stream option.  This does exactly what you want, but there is a trade-off between space and time, and using the streaming parser is usually more difficult.

In the present case, for example, using the non-streaming (i.e., default) parser, one could simply write:

```
jq '.a, .b, .d' big.json
```

Using the streaming parser, you would have to write something like:

```
jq --stream 'select(length==2 and .[0][-1] == ("a","b","d"))[1]' big.json
```

or if you prefer:

```
jq -c --stream '["a","b","d"] as $keys | select(length==2 and (.[0][-1] | IN($keys[])))[1]' big.json
```

In certain cases, you could achieve significant speedup by wrapping the filter in a call to `limit`, e.g.

```
["a","b","d"] as $keys
| limit($keys|length;
    select(length==2 and .[0][-1] == ("a","b","c"))[1])
```

### Note on Java and jq

Although there are Java bindings for jq (see e.g. ": What language bindings are available for Java?" in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)), I do not know any that work with the --stream option.

However, since 2.5MB is tiny for jq, you could use one of the available Java-jq bindings without bothering with the streaming parser.