# Parse only one field in a large JSON string

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonpath

I have a JSON string of the following format:

```
{

  "foo": "small_vale"  
  "baz": "large_value"
  "bar": "another_large_value"

}
```

How can I efficiently extract `foo` while ignoring the rest of the fields?
Basically, I'm using Gson and I defined a "lean class" like that:

```
MyClass {
  private String foo;
}
```

If I'm ensuring that `foo` appears first in the JSON string, would Gson still scan the whole string, or is it smart enough to stop?

Should I use JsonPath instead?

Comment: easy way to do it, in api accept MyClass. and your MyClass add only which you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer on this question we need to see how do you parse `JSON`. I assume that you are using simplest:

```
Test test = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Test.class);
```

If this is your case, answer for your question is `Gson` is not smart enough to do that. If you check implementation of this method, you will find out:

```
public <T> T fromJson(Reader json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException, JsonIOException {
    JsonReader jsonReader = newJsonReader(json);
    Object object = fromJson(jsonReader, classOfT);
    assertFullConsumption(object, jsonReader);
    return Primitives.wrap(classOfT).cast(object);
}
```

Before method returns value, it checks whether whole `JSON` was consumed and in case not, `JsonIOException` is thrown. `Gson` internally uses `TypeAdapter` implementation for given type. For your custom `MyClass` it will use `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter` class which will consume the whole `JSON` payload. To avoid this situation you can write your own `TypeAdapter`:

```
class TestTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Test> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Test value) throws IOException {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Implement me!");
    }

    @Override
    public Test read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        Test test = new Test();

        try {
            in.beginObject();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String name = in.nextName();
                if (name.equals("foo")) {
                    test.setFoo(in.nextString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new JsonSyntaxException(e);
        }

        return test;
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Test test = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Test.class);
        Test test1 = new TestTypeAdapter().fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile));

        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(test1);
    }
}

class Test {

    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "foo='" + foo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Test{foo='small_value'}
Test{foo='small_value'}
```

As, you can see, in both cases we parsed our `small value`. You can test this code and calculate how faster custom `TypeAdapter` is for your `JSON` payload.

But in case, you have much complex situation and you need to parse much more `JSON` to find your value, try to use `JSONPath` solution. You can start from this question: [how to parse a huge JSON file without loading it in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817985/how-to-parse-a-huge-json-file-without-loading-it-in-memory).

Answer (score 1):

Your json file is not valid. Commas are missing. It should look like this:

```
{
  "foo":"small_value",
  "baz":"large_value",
  "bar":"another_large_value"
}
```

[This blog post](https://blog.overops.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/) says that Jackson or simple JSON are the fastest ways to parse big json data. Se the chapter "Big File Results" for reference.

Example code for Jackson: [Jackson JSON – Read Specific JSON Key](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial)

It shows how to parse a json file ang get a value of a specific element.

```
//read json file data to String
byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("data.json"));

//create ObjectMapper instance
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

//read JSON like DOM Parser
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonData);
JsonNode fooNode = rootNode.path("foo");
System.out.println("foo value = "+fooNode.asText());
```

Comment: A few years later that link is now redirecting to a different blog post, but I believe this is the post you are referring to: https://www.harness.io/blog/ultimate-json-library-comparison